# Data needs conversion into columns from multiple-address-object-blocks (Excel / OpenOffice )

Tags: excel, openoffice.org

Each block contains 3 addresses - name, city, state, zip - how do I break it apart in OpenOffice/Excel?

James R. Javier DDS Kent R. Nelson DDS Theodore G. Lund DDS
421 SW 335th St 1911 SW Campus Rd 2748 SW 315th St
Federal Way, WA 98023-6192 Federal Way, WA 98023-6473 Federal Way, WA 98023-7832

H. Jung Song DDS Timothy J. Weaver DDS Sang H. Bae DDS
21807 76th Ave W 21701 76th Ave W #202 13426 64th Ave W
Edmonds, WA 98026 Edmonds, WA 98026 Edmonds, WA 98026

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where your data is coming from, but if you could somehow insert a delimiter or implement a fixed field length, the 'text to columns' function in Excel will help. (Data->Text to Columns.)

Comment: The data came from OCR'd "Address Labels" - about 99% came across correctly, about 100-150 records came across as above. looking for quick way that i hadn't thought of..otherwise i might just retype. no way to insert any delimiter...the data is the data. :)

Comment: in that case, I don't know of any way to split data that has no consistency or delimiter.

Comment: looks like its a job for the peons! muauahahah :) thanks for trying, i figured it was a no go. the only consistency in the data seems to be what it contains...

Comment: I ended up using Excel extensively and wasting a lot of time. Make proper data models/formats!